# trouble rendering cloth modifier

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision, hook-modifier

I made a cloth simulation with colissions that looks great on the viewport but when rendering it becomes weird . The animation its about a girl who opens her closet and a bunch of clothes fall. I´ve tried baking all dinamics before rendering but no changes. I used an empty and used it with the hook modifier to take the clothes out of the closet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: without seeing all of your settings - we can only guess around or give "random" tipps. So please provide blend file so we can check it out. Thx.

Comment: Sorry, "it becomes weird" without any further explanation of what is happening does not really give any hints for us on how to solve whatever the problem is.

Comment: Look for any settings in the modifiers which differ between viewport and render

Comment: I would change the order of the last three modifiers (*Solidify*, *Collision*, *Cloth*) to (*Cloth*, *Collision*, *Solidify*) because they work top-down. The *Cloth* modifier deforms the mesh and you want to have the collision detection on the deformed mesh, I guess. The *Solidify* modifier is just cosmetic (thickness) and can go last. This way the *Cloth* modifier does not need to deal with the extra geometry that the *Solidify* modifier creates.

Comment: Speaking of modifiers, make sure the *Subdivision Surface* modifier has the same number of level for *View* and *Render* mode! The default setting (1 and 2) differs and this will mess up your *Cloth* simulation for sure when you render it.... yeah, basically, what Robin Betts meant